# play-sbt 2.5.6 plugin giving unresolved dependencies error

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to install play-sbt 2.5.6 plugin.
I have made the build.sbt, build.properties and 
plugins.sbt as given at the playframework site.
I am using sbt 0.13.12.
On launching sbt I get the following error message:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0: configuration not found in aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.sonatype.sisu#sisu-guice;3.1.0 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
[warn]        +- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:3.1.0
[warn]        +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.0.0.M5
[warn]        +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.2.2
[warn]        +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.2.2
[warn]        +- org.vafer:jdeb:1.3
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.0.3 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.5.5 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (D:\MyData\play\temp\project\plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:temp-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0: configuration not found in aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.sonatype.sisu#sisu-guice;3.1.0 compile
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
...
```

I hope someone can explain how to solve this problem.

edits:
**plugins.sbt**
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.6")

**build.sbt**
name := "my-first-app"

version := "1.0.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).

**build.properties**
sbt.version=0.13.12

Comment: Can you provide us the effective build.sbt, build.properties and plugins.sbt you have?

Comment: I have added the contents of the three files in the main question

Answer (score 0):

Delete ~.ivy2/aopalliance directory and it should work fine.

rm -rf ~.ivy2/aopalliance
activator ui